# Wrapping kafka asyc mechanism with a sync http proxy (envoy)

Tags: apache-kafka, envoyproxy

Is it possíble to setup envoy to receive HTTP request send it to a kafka topic wait for response related to that message from another topic(s) and create http response based on the kafka response?

Comment: Why need envoy? Confluent has a Kafka REST Proxy project... But Kafka does not fit into request/reply, and to my knowledge, Envoy includes no Kafka consumer usage to do what you're asking

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for your response, I did not try Kafka Rest but as the documentation said it is not used for this specific usage that I have mentioned. it is only for pushing messages into on topic or get messages from a topic. I need a mechanism to convert Sync requests into Async requests by proxying two Kafka topics (one for input and another for output) I think there should be a ready to use solution for this requirement)

Comment: @OneCricketeer conclusion to envoy was based on this article: https://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2020/05/25/api-management-gateway-apache-kafka-comparison-mulesoft-kong-apigee/

Comment: That's a TCP filter, not HTTP sync/async proxy. Refer docs https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/network_filters/kafka_broker_filter

Answer (score 0):

I found this implementation for bridging Sync HTTP to Async Kafka but I think there is some more enterprise solution for such a generic problem:
[kafka - http bridge](https://dzone.com/articles/synchronous-kafka-using-spring-request-reply-1)